# Google Bigquery , array_length returning incorrect # within an array

Tags: google-bigquery

```
   WITH items AS
  (SELECT ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears', 'grapes'] as list)
   select array_length(list) from items
```

When I run this query, I get a result of 4 for array length

```
   WITH items AS
  (SELECT 'apples', 'bananas', 'pears', 'grapes' as list)
  select array_length(array<string>[list]) from items;
```

This one however, only returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the numbers are correct!

To see why you wrong: run first below

```
#standardSQL
WITH items AS (SELECT 'apples', 'bananas', 'pears', 'grapes' AS list)
SELECT * FROM items
```

with output

```
Row f0_     f1_     f2_     list     
1   apples  bananas pears   grapes
```

so as you can see that `list` column has actually just one value - `grapes`, so no even chances for four values to drive array size of 4

But then, even if you would define list as a string with list of values - like `SELECT 'apples, bananas, pears, grapes' AS list` it is still just one string value as far as ARRAY is concerned

If you want to treat such list as ARRAY with four elements - you can try below approach

```
#standardSQL
WITH items AS (SELECT 'apples, bananas, pears, grapes' AS list)
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(list)) FROM items
```

with output

```
Row f0_  
1   4
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first query you are creating an array with the elements and naming this array as **list**:

```
   WITH items AS
  (SELECT ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears', 'grapes'] as list)
   select array_length(list) from items
```

In the second query you are selecting 4 strings and naming the last string as **list**

```
WITH items AS
  (SELECT 'apples', 'bananas', 'pears', 'grapes' as list)
  select array_length(array<string>[list]) from items;
```

In this case, when you run `select array_length(array<string>[list]) from items;` you are transforming this last string named **list** into an array of strings. As its a single string, your final array will have only one position.